# Why are Oxyuranus snake species named Taipan?

Tags: zoology, taxonomy, nomenclature, herpetology, etymology

It is interesting, why are *Oxyuranus* species called *Taipan*. The snakes are Australian but *taipan* looks like of Chinese origin word (it means *big shot* - important person).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An answer is found at the Wikipedia page for [Taipan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taipan):

> The common name, taipan, was coined by anthropologist Donald Thomson after the word used by the Wik-Mungkan Aboriginal people of central Cape York Peninsula, Queensland, Australia.

This passage is citing *Sutton. 1995. Wik Ngathan Dictionary* as support. I cannot evaluate the truth in this statement though.

For another reference see [McKnight. 1981. *The Wik-mungkan concept Nganwi: a study of mystical power and sickness in an Australian tribe*. Bijdragen tot de Taal-, Land- en Volkenkunde 137](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/27863347?uid=47232&uid=3738984&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=47230&uid=3&uid=67&uid=62&sid=21106376592071), which refers to *Taipan* as the [Rainbow serpent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Serpent) (an Aboriginal mythical creature) of the Wik-Mungkan tribe.

Even more folklore is found in [McNamee. 2000. *The Serpent's Tale: Snakes in Folklore and Literature*](https://books.google.se/books?id=oHJxueGDR2YC&pg=PA39&#v=onepage&q&f=false) in "*Taipan the snake and the blue-tongued lizard*".